# How to move a whole ElasticSearch 0.20.6 Cluster?

Tags: java, elasticsearch, ubuntu-12.04

we are running an old ElasticSearch 0.20.6 Cluster on a legacy-system, which we now need to move and scale down to a single machine, since the service is rarely used anymore.

We can not upgrade the ES, since afaik that would imply updating the Java clients, which we can not do.

Does anyone know a "simple" way to move all indices to a new machine running 0.20.6?

Answer (score 0):

Try moving your /data directory.